# DB2 docker - Unable to map other port than 50000

Tags: docker, db2

My actual `docker-compose.yml`

```
version: '3.9'

services:

    db2:
        image: ibmcom/db2
        container_name: db2
        privileged: true
        ports:
            - "50000:50000"
        environment:
            - LICENSE=accept
            - DB2INSTANCE=...
            - DB2INST1_PASSWORD=...
            - DBNAME=...
        volumes:
            - database:/database

volumes:
    database:
```

Is working fine.

Now I'd like to use other port.  Let's say `54830`.

I tried with

```
    ports:
        - "54830:50000"
```

But it is not working.  I always got a `connection refused` when trying to connect with a client.

I don't understand why and what to do for having it working.

Comment: Are you still doing `EXPOSE 50000`?

Comment: You mean in the docker image ?  It's the ibm's image, not mine.  So I'm not doing any EXPOSE 50000 by myself.